# CSS transform scale on a container that has height of non-integer numbers causes rendering issue in Chrome and Firefox browsers

Tags: css, transform, scale, css-transforms

There's a problem that I'm facing in the Chrome and Firefox browsers. Whenever I'm trying to `transform: scale` a container, that doesn't have a height of whole pixels, it has some strange rendering issues.

I've created an example, where this problem can be seen. When you click on the cells in the middle row, the cell container shifts (jumps or resizes) by 1px, either doubling the gap on the bottom side or entirely hiding it.

Here's the example code:

```css
.grid-container-1,
.grid-container-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1px;
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container-1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid-container-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.grid-item:focus {
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

```html
<pre>300x300px:</pre>
<div class="grid-container-1">
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>

  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>

  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>

<pre>300x250px:</pre>
<div class="grid-container-2">
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>

  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>

  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```

This doesn't appear to happen in the Safari browser though. Only on Chrome and Firefox browsers (from what I've tested so far).

When I adjust the container size, so that cells have pixel perfect height, it works just fine on any browser. However, I in my scenario, I cannot guarantee that all cells will have height of whole numbers, so that is not the solution for my problem.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm looking at the right thing. I see a thickening of the bottom gap during the transform, and then it 'recovers' (i.e. the cell goes back to the right height). Seen on Chrome and FF on Windows 10 (but not on Edge). Am I looking at the right problem?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. It 'recovers' after the transition ends. However, even if you apply transform effect on a specific cell manually, it will show this rendering issue.